# How to trim a series of arrays in Matlab by eliminating elements

Tags: arrays, matlab

I wonder if there is a way of looping through a number of arrays of different sizes and trimming data from the beginning of each array in order to achieve the same amount of elements in each array?

For instance, if I have:

```
 A = [4     3     9     8    13]
 B = [15     2     6    11     1    12     8     9    10    13     4]
 C = [2     3    11    12    10     9    15     4    14]
```

and I want B an C to lose some elements at the beginning, such that they end up being 5 elements in length, just like A, to achieve:

```
 A = [4     3     9     8    13]
 B = [8     9    10    13     4]
 C = [10     9    15     4    14]
```

How would I do that?

EDIT/UPDATE:

I have accepted the answer proposed by @excaza, who wrote a nice function called "naivetrim". I saved that function as a .m script and then used it: First I define my three arrays and, as @excaza suggests, called the function:

```
 [A, B, C] = naivetrim(A, B, C);
```

Another solution variation that worked for me - based on @Sardar_Usama's answer below (looping it). I liked this as well, because it was a bit more straightforward (with my level, I can follow what is happening in the code)

```
A = [4     3     9     8    13]
B = [15     2     6    11     1    12     8     9    10    13     4]
C = [2     3    11    12    10     9    15     4    14]

arrays = {A,B,C}

temp = min([numel(A),numel(B), numel(C)]);  %finding the minimum number of elements
% Storing only required elements

for i = 1:size(arrays,2)
    currentarray = arrays{i}
    arrays(i) = {currentarray(end-temp+1:end)}
end
```

Comment: How many different arrays are there?

Comment: `[ ]` are used for arrays/matrices in MATLAB, not `( )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A naive looped solution:

```
function testcode()
% Sample data arrays
A = [4, 3, 9, 8, 13];
B = [15, 2, 6, 11, 1, 12, 8, 9, 10, 13, 4];
C = [2, 3, 11, 12, 10, 9, 15, 4, 14];

[A, B, C] = naivetrim(A, B, C);
end

function varargout = naivetrim(varargin)
% Assumes all inputs are vectors

% Find minumum length
lengths = zeros(1, length(varargin), 'uint32');  % Preallocate
for ii = 1:length(varargin)
    lengths(ii) = length(varargin{ii});
end

% Loop through input arrays and trim any that are longer than the shortest
% input vector
minlength = min(lengths);
varargout = cell(size(varargin));  % Preallocate
for ii = 1:length(varargout)
    if length(varargin{ii}) >= minlength
        varargout{ii} = varargin{ii}(end-minlength+1:end);
    end
end
end
```

Which returns:

```
A =

     4     3     9     8    13


B =

     8     9    10    13     4


C =

    10     9    15     4    14
```

If you have a large number of arrays you may be better off with alternative intermediate storage data types, like [cells](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) or [structures](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html), which would be "simpler" to assign and iterate through.

---

Timing code for a few different similar approaches can be found in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/sco1/048c10fd2dd529c5833a1d3097fd9edd).

```
Performance Profile, MATLAB (R2016b)

Number of Elements in A: 999999
Number of Elements in B: 424242
Number of Elements in C: 101325

Trimming, deletion:        0.012537 s
Trimming, copying:         0.000430 s
Trimming, cellfun copying: 0.000493 s
```

Comment: Thanks excaza, as a naive user, I am not so used to working with functions. I tried saving this as naivetrim.m script and run it, but nothing happens, there is no error, but also if I type "A" I get a "Undefined function or variable 'A'". Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You need to [declare outputs to the function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html).

Comment: Thanks, excaza! This seems to be a clever way of doing this trimming by usign functions. But I have to admit I was not able to follow how to implement it (due to my knowledge level), so I cannot validate it. From the link you have sent I thought I forgot to input something important, but it seems that "function varargout = naivetrim(varargin)" actually IS the declaration part.

Comment: Are you saving the entire post as `naivetrim.m` or just `naievetrim`? How are you attempting to use it?

Comment: Got it! I was saving the entire post in the beginning. Now I just saved the second function and added it to the path so Matlab knows what it is. I checked "which naivetrim" to see whether it can locate it - and it could. Then I just typed the three arrays and the [A, B, C] = naivetrim(A, B, C) and it worked (outside of any other function). What I am trying to say is I figured out that the anivetrim is the functiona and then I use the function anywhere else I want. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If there are not many matrices then it can be done as:

```
temp = min([numel(A),numel(B), numel(C)]);  %finding the minimum number of elements
% Storing only required elements
A = A(end-temp+1:end);   
B = B(end-temp+1:end);
C = C(end-temp+1:end);
```

Comment: Thanks Sardar_Usama, this seems quite straightforward. I am now trying to implement it as a loop